# git branch list the branches with upstream

Tags: git

Git i have default master branch and origin/master.

To list the remote and local branches i used git branch -a

[image: List the remote and local branches]

Next when i am using cmd git branch -vv

[image]

when i am using git branch -vv inside the box with color of blue [origin/master] is available so what is mean by that ?

Could you please some one help me ?

Answer (score 4):

The text in blue is showing you the upstream branch which is associated with the local branch.  i.e. `origin/master` is the upstream branch of `master`.

More information here: https://git-scm.com/book/ch3-5.html

Answer (score 0):

That shows you which branch that branch is tracking. In your case, `master` is tracking `origin/master`.

Ttracking branches, when pushed, push to the branch they track.